# BigVideo.js - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add the BigVideo.js plugin to my website, however when I follow the simple example they provide on their website as seen below

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/BigVideo/lib/bigvideo.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var BV;
        $(function() {
            // initialize BigVideo
            BV = new $.BigVideo();
            BV.init();
            BV.show('http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',{ambient:true});
        });
    </script>
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Can anyone help with WHY I'm getting this error?  Is there something I'm missing here?  Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason, but you are missing jQuery UI as dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error often comes from a missing JQuery library, I checked your plugin website and it says that it needs JQuery-UI but you didn't include it.

Hope that it fixes your issue